# Notes and Attachments - differentiate by ContentType , query

Tags: attachment, notes

Is there any way to distinguish between the types of attachments. Essentially I wanted to create a new field on type on the attachments object for distinguishing between pictures, docs and excel etc. Then I want to see the different types of attachments(based on the field) separately on a VF page. Please suggest some ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Notes and attachments both are different sobject.

Comment: @Ratan Talking about attachments. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Ohh are you looking for Type of attachment like doc image pdf etc? So you can use `contentType` field on Attachment....  Sorry your question was bit confusing

Comment: @Ratan Thank a lot and I agree on the confusing part.

Comment: No problem.. your issue resolved?

Comment: @Ratan Yeah decided to go with ContentType for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `ContentType` on attachment to difference between their file extension.
According to the docs

> ContentType   Type string
>
> Properties Create, Filter, Group, Nillable,Sort, Update
>
> Description The content type of the attachment. If the
>   Don't allow HTML uploads as attachments or document records security
>   setting is enabled for your organization, you cannot upload files with
>   the following file extensions: .htm, .html, .htt, .htx, .mhtm, .mhtml,
>   .shtm, .shtml, .acgi, .svg.

[Attachment Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_attachment.htm)